# parallelepiped volume with a variable

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Giving this three vectors :
$$ \vec{a} = \vec{i} + \vec{j} - \vec{k}$$$$\vec{b}=2\vec{i}+\vec{j}-\vec{k}$$ $$\vec{c} = m\vec{i} - \vec{j} + m\vec{k} $$

What value must have $m$, if the volume of the **parrallelepiped** generated with the vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ is equal to $9$ unit cube?

I suppose the volume is giving by the formula : ($\vec{a} \wedge \vec{b}) \cdot \vec{c} = 9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your idea for how to start this problem is a good one. Since you have explicit formulas for $x\wedge y$ and $x\cdot y$, you can apply your specific vectors given here to write down a polynomial equation in $m$; solve it and you're done.

Comment: Can you elaborate. Maybe with an example. ;)

Comment: I could write up an example, but I don't think it is necessary. Can you solve for $a\wedge b$?

Comment: Yes. It's after I don't know how to resolve. Now I know the $\vec{a} \wedge \vec{b} = -\vec{j} - \vec{k}$.

Comment: Can you solve for $(-j-k)\cdot c$?

Comment: I do not get $m=-1$ (and I also get $2$ when plugging in $-1$): you probably made an algebra mistake. If you want more help, I'd rather you edit the question to show your working, since I cannot ask a leading question to fix algebraic errors.